# The equivalence relation induced by a vector field

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a manifold and $v:M\longrightarrow TM$ is a vector field.

My question is that:
How does $v$ induce an equivalence relation on $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $v$ as a "flow field" and consider the differential equation
$$\dot x(t)=v\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\ .$$
There will be integral curves, or *orbits*, of this flow. Call two points $a$,$b\in M$ *equivalent*, if there is an orbit connecting them in finite time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.